Schwarz's Lemma modification
Here is the problem :
Assume $f$ analytic on $|z| < 1$, with $|f(z)| \leq M$ for all $|z| < 1$. Then if $f(\alpha) = 0$ for some $\alpha, |\alpha| < 1$ then show that $|f(z)| \leq M |\frac{z-\alpha}{1-\bar{\alpha}z}|$ when $|z| < 1$. If $|f(z)| = M$ somewhere then in this disk I understand that $f(z) = 0$ everywhere in this disk by the maximum modulus principle and then the inequality is trivial, but otherwise I'm unsure how $|f(z)| < M$ as a strict upper bound would allow me to proceed, or if that's even where I'm supposed to go with the problem. Any and all help/hints would be appreciated.

Seeing the title, you did notice that this was similar to the Schwarz lemma. Hint: you can actually create a function $g$, directly related to $f$, which satisfies the conditions of the Schwarz lemma.

I see now, thank you for your help
